# Is it safe to silently catch ClassCastException when searching for a specific value?

Tags: java, collections, exception, classcastexception

Suppose I am implementing a sorted collection (simple example - a `Set` based on a sorted array.)  Consider this (incomplete) implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortedArraySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SortedArraySet(Collection<E> source, Comparator<E> comparator) {
    this.comparator = (Comparator<Object>) comparator;
    this.array = source.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(this.array, this.comparator);
}

@Override
public boolean contains(Object key) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key, comparator) >= 0;
}

    private final Object[] array;

    private final Comparator<Object> comparator;

}
```

Now let's create a set of integers

```
Set<Integer> s = new SortedArraySet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), null);
```

And test whether it contains some specific values:

```
System.out.println(s.contains(2));
System.out.println(s.contains(42));
System.out.println(s.contains("42"));
```

The third line above will throw a `ClassCastException`.  Not what I want.  I would prefer it to return `false` (as `HashSet` does.)

I can get this behaviour by catching the exception and returning false:

```
@Override    
public boolean contains(Object key) {
    try {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key, comparator) >= 0;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Assuming the `source` collection is correctly typed*, what could go wrong if I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing an `instanceof` check as the first line of your `contains()` and returning `false` if it fails?

Comment: @dkarp, yes, my collection class is generic and thanks to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure) it does not know what the type `E` is at run-time.

Comment: Yep, that'd be a reason.

Comment: I just saw the line in your code, `Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(array), this.comparator);` and want to note that `Arrays` has a `sort` and a `binarySearch` method, too, which works on an array directly.

Comment: @Christian Semrau, you're right.  I've changed the example to use those metheds.  It doesn't affect the main point of the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue with this as the Javadoc for [`Collection.contains`](http://xlct.it/eVhbcn) clearly states that throwing a `ClassCastException`is optional.

The only *issue* I see is that if you have a bug *somewhere* not throwing an exception will prevent you to pinpoint it.

Comment: @finnw, well, OpenJDK's HashSet doesn't catch any exception.  It just [loops through](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#8WzsEc7XzB0/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java&q=openjdk%20HashMap.java&l=351) and checks `==` and `.equals`.  That doesn't mean your implementation is wrong (though it will give weird results if the Comparator isn't consistent with equals).

Comment: If the classes that are put in a `HashSet` do obey their contracts, then `HashSet` does not throw a `ClassCastException` (or any exception) if you call `contains()` with an incompatible value. As Matthew noted, it only calls `equals` on the value, and the contract of `equals` forbids throwing exceptions. The weird results for a Comparator that is inconsistent with equals would be produced in a similar way by a `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeSet` class does throw a `ClassCastException` for incompatible arguments to `contains()` (incompatible for the `Comparator` used by the set). So there is nothing wrong with throwing that exception. Just make sure you document that this may happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legitimate to let a CCE throw from contains().  However, many collection implementations catch that and return false, which I consider to also be perfectly legitimate, and in fact is the more user-friendly behavior.

In equals() you don't have the choice; you have to catch that CCE.

Catching an unchecked exception should always feel dirty, but sometimes it is the right thing to do.